# Nhaarman ListViewAnimations: ListView item height changes after previous item dismissal

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I've started to use [nhaarman ListViewAnimations library](http://nhaarman.github.io/ListViewAnimations/) and faced the following issue: after ListView item dismissal the next one item changes its height:

[image: Item before "444" was dismissed]

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        dynamicListView = (DynamicListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, new ArrayList<> (Arrays.asList(new String[]{"111", "222", "333", "444", "555", "661", "277", "388", "499", "115", "221", "233", "443", "664", "5434"}))
        );
        dynamicListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        dynamicListView.enableSwipeToDismiss(
                new OnDismissCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDismiss(@NonNull final ViewGroup listView, @NonNull final int[] reverseSortedPositions) {
                        for (int position : reverseSortedPositions) {
                            arrayAdapter.remove(arrayAdapter.getItem(position));
                        }
                    }
                }
        );
    }
```

What is going on?